# Site Collection does not exist in database. Site collection will not be moved

Tags: 2013, site-collection, content-database, database

I am trying to move the site collection `http://<webapp>/dealers/1020` from content database WSS_Content_2 to WSS_Content_7

I run the command:

```
Move-SPSite http://<webapp>/dealers/1020 -DestinationDatabase WSS_Content_7
```

I am getting this error:

```
Move-SPSite : Site collection http://<webapp>/dealers/1020
does not exist in database WSS_Content_2. Site collection will not be moved.
At line:1 char:1
+ Move-SPSite http://<webapp>/dealers/1020
-DestinationDatabase WS ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...PCmdletMoveSite:
SPCmdletMoveSite) [Move-SPSite], SPCmdletException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletMoveSite
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: are both DB on the same SQL server and attached to same web app?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Yes they are on the Same SQL Server and attached to the same web app

Comment: what happen when you run get-spsite against the site collection.....

Comment: It works fine...but when I save it to $site and run $site.ContentDatabase it shows that it is on WSS_Content_7 already...weird.  I will look around and see if I can find anything else useful.

Comment: did you run the command twice?

Comment: Good question...but no.  Unless a long time ago it was run by someone else.  But how would it know it was on WSS_Content_2?  Is a piece of it still there? I am going to try and move it to a db other than WSS_Content_7 and see what happens.

Comment: ok. i am not sure if their is any property which tells u about the history of db....from central admin you can check it in which database it is.

Comment: Sounds like you have not run the IIS reset yet. See this Technet article for details. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ff607915.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396